# Born-Oppenheimer approximation in many-body perturbation theory

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, many-body, phonons, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In order to obtain phonon spectrum, we usually do Born-Oppenheimer approximation and assume that the electrons are always at the ground state when the atoms move, and by calculating the force on each atom (usually using DFT) we are able to assemble the dynamic matrix of the atoms and obtain the phonon modes. After this we can calculate the electron-phonon vertex and then do Feynman diagrammatic calculations to get things like polaron.

So the whole formalism is based on the BO approximation. The question then is how we can write down a set of Feynman rules about both electrons and atoms without the BO approximation. Can we still define phonons (hence phonon propagator, etc.) in this case? If we already have a theory under the BO approximation, is it possible to, say, add more interaction vertices and/or adjust the coupling strength to go beyond BO?

Comment: We can't really start with a "fundamental" theory because in that case we would be solving the complete many-body theory for atoms, which would give us things like chemical orbitals and the x-ray spectrum. The problem is only tractable if we start with an effective field theory for the solid that only treats the "loosely bound" electrons. The "full" treatment would reproduce phonons in some approximation, but they may not just drop out in a trivial way, since the multi-electron wave function lives in a very high dimensional space that is not the space that determines the phonon spectrum.